# How can I listen to my iPhone's audio output, using the headphones connected to my Mac?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I have an iPhone 7 Plus. It, like all other phones of its type, has no headphone jack, and I have no adapter. However, I also have a MacBook Pro (2014), running Sierra.

When I'm at home, is there some way I can have the iPhone send all its audio output to my computer, so that I can use my computer's headphones as my iPhone's headphones?

Note: I tried using Audio Midi Setup to treat my iPhone as an audio input. It didn't work when playing games, which was the audio I really wanted to pipe in.

Comment: Apple's Airplay feature is likely able to do this, have you looked into using Airplay?

Comment: Perhaps this is half of an answer, a how-to on getting iPhone audio into a Mac=>  https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/play-audio-iphone-mac/  I was not able to pass through the audio, only see virtual VU meter wiggle with audio input.